# Erlang distribution with different rate per variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

According to Wikipedia:
Erlang distribution is the distribution of a sum of $k$ independent exponential variables with mean $\mu$ each.

So if I want a distribution of a sum of $k$ independent exponential variables with different mean values ($\mu_i$), then what distribution should I refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of distribution is referred to as "hypoexponential distribution".